# Need help in SVN Branch/Tag/Merge

Tags: svn, version-control

Can some one please explain, what does SVN branch, tag, merge do? Why they are there? And how to best utilize them.

I have read some documentation on their website but still not clear how to best utilize them and for what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my question is answered here:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.whatis.html

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.tags.html

Answer (score 1):

- Branch and Tag (are the same in SVN technically): "copy" a path to a new path
- Merge: Apply changes from one path, which occurred over a number of revisions to another path

Comment: You have to explain more, how much you know yourself. Do you understand the concepts of revision, path, commit, etc in SVN?

Comment: yes, but basics.. I know about revisions, commits, reverts.. but no more than that.

I'm specifically also interested to know what does Branches & Tags  or Merge do in Eclipse SVN plugin or Visual Studio AnkhSVN, and how to use them and for what?